# Get the repetition of number in the form of dimension in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, dimensions

I have a 10x20 numpy array

```
[[255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255]]
```

I want to get the repetition of number 0(island of 0's) in the form of a array of dimensions . Like in the example above if I pass the number `0` as parameter the function should go from top to down through the matrix and then go from left to right resulting in the dimensional array. The output for above example should be

```
#Zeroes repetition dimensions
[[20,4],[3,5],[2,5]]
```

How can I get this output. Any numpy functions to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recently had a similar interview question. I recommend first figuring out the bounds of each rectangle of 0s (top left and bottom right). If you subtract x2-x1, you get how many 0s repeat horizontally, and y2-y1 to figure out how many 0s repeat vertically.

Comment: What if the 6th row were : `[255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255]` and `7th` as : `[255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255]`, i.e. the island of three 0s is shifted to the left for the `7th`?

Comment: Seems that your problem has multiple solutions, as stated. Why not extend the lower blocks further upwards, and slice up the remaining stuff on top differently? I suppose a minimal amount of cuts is implied; but I fear that to get that in the general case is a terribly difficult problem; and there certainly is no builtin numpy function for it.

Comment: Any algorithms that you prefer?

Comment: Please may you  add some sub-steps (explaining 'I want to get the repetition of number 0/ island of 0's in the form of a array of dimensions ') between your 10x20 arrray, and the expected result [20,4],[3,5],[2,5]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use itertools `groupby` for this:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter
arr=np.array([[255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255]])

val_to_check=0
agg_res=[] 
for a in arr:
    groups = groupby(a)
    temp = [[label, sum(1 for _ in group)] for label, group in groups]
    for t in temp:
        if t[0]==val_to_check:
            agg_res.append(t)

res_to_group=[l[1] for l in agg_res]
final_res=Counter(res_to_group)
#or, in list form: 
res_list=map(list,final_res.items())
```

output:

```
[[2, 5], [3, 5], [20, 4]]
```

Or, if you want, as a function:

```
def find_islands(arr,val):
    agg_res=[] 
    for a in arr:
        groups = groupby(a)
        temp = [[label, sum(1 for _ in group)] for label, group in groups]
        for t in temp:
            if t[0]==val:
                agg_res.append(t)

    res_to_group=[l[1] for l in agg_res]
    final_res=Counter(res_to_group)
    #or, in list form: 
    return map(list,final_res.items())
```

example run:

```
In[65]: find_islands(arr,255)
Out[65]: [[2, 5], [20, 1], [6, 5], [7, 5]]
```

Comment: Code doesn't word if  the island of 0s is shifted to the left or right by one.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean (give an example array where it doesn't work)?

Comment: if the 6th row were : `[255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,2‌​55,255,255]` and 7th as : `[255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,2‌​55,255,255]` the output should be `[[20,4],[3,2],[3,2],[3,1],[2,5]]`

Comment: why `[3,2],[3,2],[3,1]` and not `[3,5]`?

Comment: and if you don't want the aggregation so why `[20,4]` and not `[20,1],[20,1],[20,1],[20,1]`, for example?

Comment: That was a wrong example though, there are lot of combinations that can be made. Thanks for the effort mate.

Comment: Glad to help, but please explain me if you want the aggregation or not?

Comment: I want the aggregation based on the number of zeros together top down.